# Trying to make every other house's door green

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What my task is, is to draw a house then use a loop (at the bottom) to fill the canvas with the houses instead of manually placing each one.

Well I'm trying to work how to make every other house's door green. I've been trying to hack away at code for awhile now but I cannot figure it out.

I know all my house pieces should be in functions and what not but that is a later task for the work I am doing! Here's my code:

```
//Check to see if the browser supports
//the addEventListener function
if(window.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener
    (
        'load', //this is the load event
        onLoad, //this is the evemnt handler we going to write
        false //useCapture boolen value
    );
}

//the window load event handler
function onLoad()
{
    var canvas;     
    var context;


    //this function will intialise our variables
    function initialise()
    {


        // Fune the canvas element using its id attribute.
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        //if it couldn't be found
        if (!canvas)
        {
            //make a message bok appear with an error message
            alert('Error: i cannot find this "canvas" of which you speak. Please re-evaluate your life choices.');
            return;
        }
        //check if there is any getContext function
        if(!canvas.getContext)
        {
            alert('Error no cavnas.getContext could be found');
            return;
        }
        //get the 2D canvas context.
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if(!context)
        {
            alert('Error failed to getCOntext');
            return;
        }

        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
    }

    // this is a little help tool for me as i'm awful at working out co-ordinates
    function getPosition(e)
    {
        var x = e.x;
        var y = e.y;
        x -=canvas.offsetLeft;
        y -=canvas.offsetTop;
        alert("x:" +x+ "y:"+y);
    }

    //this function will draw on the canvas for me!
    function draw()
    {
        context.fillStyle = 'grey';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }


    // pX and pY are the parameters are going to be used so that the inside of the house body becomes the drawing canvas.
    function drawHouse(pX ,pY)
    {
        //body
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.lineWidth = "5";
        context.rect(pX,pY, 160,110);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        //roof
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.moveTo(pX,pY-1);;
        context.lineTo(pX+80, pY-95);
        context.lineTo(pX+160, pY-1);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        //door 
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "green";
        context.fillSStyle = "red";
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.rect(pX+55,pY+30, 50, 80);
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        //handle
        var radius = 5;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(pX+93, pY+75, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'purple';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();

        //window Left
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.rect(pX+12,pY+30, 30, 60);
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        //window Filler left vertically
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(pX+26.5,pY+30);
        context.lineTo(pX+26.5, pY+90);
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        //Window filler left horizontally
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(pX+41, pY+60);
        context.lineTo(pX+11,pY+60);
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        //Window Right
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.rect(pX+117,pY+30, 30, 60);
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        //window filler right vertically
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(pX+131.5,pY+30);
        context.lineTo(pX+131.5, pY+90);
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        //window Filler right horizontally
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(pX+147, pY+60);
        context.lineTo(pX+117,pY+60);
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
    }

    initialise();
    draw();
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var pX=0+160*i;

        for(var b=0; b < 5; b++)
        {
            var pY=100+210*b;
            drawHouse(pX,pY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just change `context.fillStyle = 'purple';` and `context.strokeStyle = 'black';` with the color you want before calling `fill` or `stroke`. Those function also support hexa (`="#4466FF"`) and RGBA (`="RGBA(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter to `drawHouse`:

```
function drawHouse(pX, pY, drawGreen) {
   // ...
   if (drawGreen)
       context.fillStyle = "green";
   else
       context.fillSStyle = "red";     
   // ...
}
```

And then, pass it accordingly. For example:

```
// before your loop
var paintGreen = false;

// In the inner for
var pY=100+210*b;
drawHouse(pX,pY,paintGreen);
paintGreen = !paintGreen; // alternate
```

Comment: I'll try that now :).

Comment: Thanks man it worked! I did as you said and added the parameter to the drawHouse function. Did the IF/ELSE (Didn't know you didn't need the {} for the if else statements - so cheers). Finnaly within the in the Inner loop added "   drawHouse(pX,pY,drawGreen);
     drawGreen = !drawGreen;"